# TabBarController NavigationController with black backgroundbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

I've placed this code my applicationDidFinishLaunching method, to get a black Navigationbar.

```
rootTabBarController.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
rootTabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
```

its working fine, but when the user rearranges the Icons in the editmode, i'm getting a default blue navigation bar.

Can anyone help me to avid blue navigationbars at all ?

btw: big thanks to the genius crowd!

Comment: try adding your code to -(void)viewWillAppear instead.

Comment: I have it in my applicationDidFinishLaunching method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i have a solution, **thx to AAA4 from apple forum**

Implement the following delegate method in application delegate class:
Please ensure you have set delegate of UITabBarController

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)controller willBeginCustomizingViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers {
UIView *editView = [controller.view.subviews objectAtIndex:1];

// change backgroundColor of Edit View
editView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];



// change color of Nav Bar in Edit View
UINavigationBar *modalNavBar = [editView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
modalNavBar.tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

// change title of Edit View
modalNavBar.topItem.title = @"Edit Tabs";

}
```